# when a table trigger fires, what user does the trigger execute as

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, trigger

I have a table that I am using Insert/Update/Delete triggers to audit. I want to restrict access to the audit table so that only the triggers can write to it. What I am trying to find out is, what user would those triggers count as for inserting records into the audit table.

EDIT: Since phil showed me the documentation in his comment for how it is determined, this changes my question a little.

What is a good method to restrict access to the audit table so that only the triggers can insert records?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/manage-trigger-security?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you want it to execute under a different context, use [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to elevate permissions with `EXECUTE AS` with ownership chaining. To ensure rows are inserted into the audit table only via the trigger, simply don't grant `INSERT` permissions on the audit table. As long as all the objects are owned by the same user (e.g. dbo), the [ownership chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authorization-and-permissions-in-sql-server) will be unbroken and permit the trigger to insert into the audit tables without direct permissions.

Comment: Currently the users who have access to the database this table resides in mostly have the db_datawriter role. Wouldn't that allow them access to the table by default?

Comment: Yes, db_datawriter implictly grants insert permissions on all user tables. Personally, I prefer avoiding the built-in roles and explictly grant permissions to roles on only those objects needed, following the security principles of role-based access conrol and least privilege. But you could still use `db_datawriter` and explictly `DENY INSERT ON YourAuditTable TO public;` to get the job done.